# How to run command-line application from the terminal?

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm a recent convert from Windows to Macbook Pro. I am getting use to Xcode. One thing that I would enjoy is when running a debug application in the terminal. Currently, I have to press Command+R for it to compile and run in Xcode. To have the application run in the terminal, I have to do an additional step by opening the Products folder, right click the application, then 'Open as Exterior Editor'. Then the terminal opens and runs the program.

I would like this behavior to work automatically by pressing Command+R. It seems to me like there would be a setting to direct the output.

Are there any steps to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9):

First, make a new scheme (or edit the current one) and change the executable to Terminal.app:

[image: Scheme Info]

Then, under the "Arguments" tab, make sure "Base Expansions On" is set to your App.  Then put `open -a ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}`

[image: Scheme Arguments]

The command will get expanded to something like `open -a /Users/Me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProj-abcdefghijklmnopqrrstuvwxyz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Universal.app`

`open -a` is how you open an App from the command line.

Edit: Use `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}` instead (see comments).

Comment: Thanks, though it only opens the Terminal and doesn't seem to execute the argument.

Comment: It worked after changing the argument to this: ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}   Thanks.

Comment: How would one pass arguments to that executable?

Comment: @Francisco I believe you can just add them to the end of the command `open -a ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME} ARG1 ARG2`.  Check `man open` but I think all arguments given after the app name are passed as arguments directly to the app.

Comment: @chown Unfortunately that is not the case as Xcode is using open -a.

Comment: @chown see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510815/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-program-run-with-the-open-command?noredirect=1#comment47178695_29510815)

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode (at least at 8 version) there is a checkbox "Use Terminal" available from Edit Scheme... > Run > Options > Console. With that option Xcode starts system Terminal.app with your binary attached (for debugging purposes for example).

[image]

Comment: I'm using Xcode 9 and the Console area shown above does not appear on my screen. It stops at Queue Debugging. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ChuckKrutsinger you can always install older versions of XCode from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ It's not convenient, but may help in some cases. To be honest, running with Terminal wasn't perfect because of problems launching it sometimes (usually I had to restart Terminal after second run to be able to attach to it again)

Answer (score 2):

Building on chown’s insightful idea:

1. Create an AppleScript file containing:

   ```
   on run argv
       set product to item 1 of argv
       tell application "Terminal"
           activate
           do script product
       end tell
   end run
   ```

   This AppleScript opens Terminal.app and runs the first command-line argument inside Terminal.app

   In my configuration, I saved it as `runproduct.scpt` under `$HOME/bin`.
2. Add a new scheme (you can duplicate your current scheme) or edit your current scheme. In the Info tab, set the executable to `/usr/bin/osascript`, which is a program that executes AppleScripts:

   [image]
3. In the Arguments tab, add two arguments: the AppleScript location (`${HOME}/bin/runproduct.scpt`) and the target executable location (`"${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}"`), the latter being the first argument passed to the AppleScript:

   [image]

I’m not sure if that can be made to work with the debugger, though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the tutorials overhere! Is there any way I can do this to make it work with debugger? I unfortunately need to debug a ncurses application :(

Comment: Hi Tomas, I know it is very late, but for the benefit of others, after setting your breakpoints in the code and after launching, click on Debug->Attach to Process and select the process you want LLDB attach to.