# How would I get a project to run in Terminal through Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, terminal, g++

Is it possible for me to hit run in Xcode and have my project be compiled with the g++ compiler then open a Terminal window and run it?

So pretty much I want Xcode to run these commands when I hit run:

```
g++ [source]
./a.out
```

And at some point a Terminal window will open with the program running.

How could I do this (if it's possible)?

Comment: So that didn't help? What did it do for you?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock See my answer I just posted.  Because none of the answers solve the problem in the way I was hoping for, I will not select a best answer.  Thank you for your help anyways though :)

Comment: NP, but I was just curious if your formatting (color, etc) showed up in the Terminal after running cat /tty/...?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock Actually when I tried to run `cat [tty path]` it would hang.  So I checked it out with emacs and it was empty.  I tried opening it while the program was running and after but those attempts were still in vain.

Comment: It should hang - but any new output should be displayed. I wrote a test program to echo my input and it echoed every character I input in the Terminal. So it should work for anything your program output as well.

Comment: If this is important to you please tell Apple by filing a radar http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ or using the feedback website http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780301/how-to-run-command-line-application-from-the-terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to settle with running my program in a Terminal window that I kept open while coding in Xcode.  I had Xcode compile the program to an 'a.out' file whenever I built the program in Xcode.  I did this by running a 'Run Script'.  Here's how I did it:

- Go to the screen where you can edit the build settings.
- Under 'TARGETS' in the side menu, click on your project
- Go to the 'Build Phases' tab and click the 'Add Build Phase' button
- From the list that drops down select 'Add Run Script'
- Then input what you would like Xcode to do when building the program in the box under the shell command box.  My commands were like this:

  `cd [path to program]`

  `g++ [program]`

(I can't get the block code formatting to work here).

Now all I have to do is keep a Terminal window open in the directory of the program.  I run `a.out` whenever I need to run the program in Terminal.  Not entirely automated, but there's only one extra step than I had hoped for, which isn't too bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it compile with g++ by changing the build settings (Someone else knows the specifics, i'm sure). Also, you can look at the scheme to find out where it's building the executable, from where you can use the terminal. However, I don't know why you'ed do that.. Is the debugger and log not enough?

Comment: The reason I want to do this is not because of the log or the debugger. The project I am working on runs through command-line.  Because it uses things like text/background color, it would be best if I could see it through Terminal when I run it.

Comment: Ah. Well, you can also set a custom compile folder in the scheme, instead of the default one. However, I don't think there is a way to have xcode open the terminal directly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that is what XCode does when you hit run.

That "terminal" window is what you see in the "All output" window (was called console before XCode 4).

You can enter input in that window the same as you can a terminal window....

EDIT:

You can see the same output from your app in an actual terminal. When you run the app you will get some output like this in the "All output" window:

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1705) (Fri Jul  1 10:44:54 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys010
[Switching to process 22261 thread 0x0]
```

Note the tty, in this example it is /dev/ttys010

Now, open a terminal window and cat the tty:

```
cat /dev/ttys010
```

You will now see output from your program in that terminal window.

Comment: I know that it's, in the technical sense, a "terminal" window. However, I need to be able to see color escape codes which I cannot see in that window.