# Running C scripts with terminal instead of Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, compiler-construction, terminal, user-input

Currently I am developing a couple of C programs on my mac using Xcode. There however is 1 problem. My study requires me to use some sort of input field through the coding. So for instance if the users wants to run the program 10 times or wants the program to create 10 answers. I am using "atoi(argv[1])" just to get the input from the user.

This is exactly the problem. As soon as I run the program it just starts to bug, which is normal I quess because he is waiting for the input and not receiving it or something else. Anyways I tried to solve this problem with this link: [How to run command-line application from the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780301/how-to-run-command-line-application-from-the-terminal)

This unfortunately didnt solve it either. I have already tried to re-install xcode, because just entering gcc in my terminal doesnt work either, but everytime the app store auto instals it for me.

Does anyone has a fix for my problem. I would greatly appreciate it due to the fact that next friday I have another deadline :( and I wont be getting a sufficient grade if my user input is not working.

Your help is again much appreciated!

Greetings,

Kipt Scriddy

EDIT: To clarify the problem. When running the script I want it to pop up in Terminal and wether there is an input field reguired it should ask for input. At the moment he is crashing immediatly due to the lack of input. He is not waiting for the argument to be passed from the users. He is skipping that part

Comment: Please describe your issue better; it doesn't make much sense.  What sort of apps are they?  Cocoa, command line?

Comment: Hope this is better! :) Im using Xcode, the script im writing is a "command line tool" and i want to run it in the terminal.app

Comment: Why don't you just open a terminal window, and run it there?

Comment: You need to check `argc` in the program. If it doesn't have the number of parameters you are expecting (i.e. if user did not execute the application by `./yourprogram <arg1> <arg2> ...`, then ask the user for input using `scanf`.

Comment: @Mats Petersson: that was my idea too but unfortunately my terminal is recognizing the gcc command as the c compiler.

Comment: @KiptScriddy: `gcc` is the `c` compiler? You must compile `C` code before you can run it.

Comment: @RageD Working on it now!

Comment: Is your real problem that you don't understand how/where to send command-line arguments to your program from the Xcode IDE? Couple that with failing to properly checking `argc` before dereferencing `argv[1+]` and your program is crashing?

Comment: @RageD No what I mean is that the c compiler in Xcode is not global, if you know what I mean. It is only working for Xcode and not for the terminal. I cant compile it manually

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks! Working on it now!

Comment: @WhozCraig Currently Im suspecting that my coding is wrong. I am using "int main(int argc, char *argv[])" as prototype and to get the user input atoi(argv[1]). It should only suppose to work when someone types: /phi 10. It should get the 10 so the argc[1]. Is there something wrong in my thinking?

Comment: @KiptScriddy is `/phi` the name of your program, or is that also an argument?

Comment: @WhozCraig /phi is another argument. Shouldn't argv[0] be "/phi" and argv[1] be the given integer? The thing is that the terminal is not even waiting for the required input. It is just rolling over the code auto executing it.

Comment: @KiptScriddy In your case, argv[0] = your program name, argv[1] = /phi, argv[2] = 10, which means you *better* check that **argc >=3** and either abort (return EXIT_FAILURE) or use default values instead of parsing command arguments, or you have undefined behavior.

Comment: @WhozCraig the thing is. My program should wait for the arguments. But xcode is just executing the script without even asking for the arguments :(

Comment: Your program doesn't "wait" for arguments if run from a terminal. Command line arguments are provided from the shell to your program, they are not "prompted" from your program. I assume you're not aware of how to pass arguments to your program from Xcode's IDE as if you were running from a terminal (aka `bash% ./myprog /phi 10`)

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah that is the problem. Could you tell me where I can run the program in Xcode, is there something like a terminal in Xcode that let me run it manually giving me the possibility to give arguments along the way?

Comment: @KiptScriddy Running your program is done by just executing the Run target (hit the Play button, upper left-hand corner). But you need to setup your IDE-fed command line parameters. See my answer below for details on how to set that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HOWTO Pass command line arguments to your program from Xcode IDE

1. Open your project's active **Scheme**. Easiest way to do this is from the main menu. Select **Product/Scheme/Edit Scheme...**
2. In the schema editor, you'll see several build targets on the left side; the one you want is the **"Run YourProjectName"** target. Select it.
3. On the right side you'll see four sub-tabs, including Info, Arguments, Options, and Diagnostics. Select **Arguments**
4. Add/Remove any arguments you need. In your case, add `/phi` as the first argument, then `10` as the second.

Noteworthy: This is also where you can specify the current working directory of your program at launch rather than the long, temp path Xcode uses when building your binaries. To do so:

1. Perform steps 1-2 from above.
2. Select the **Options** sub-tab
3. Click the "Use custom working directory" checkbox.
4. Specify the full path where you want Xcode to execute your program from.

That in combination with getting your parameter handling fixed in your program should get you up and running.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I know it is frustrated when your talking to a beginner! It is really appreciated. Karma + 10! PS: If I could have given you more credit I would have done it :(

Comment: @KiptScriddy You should also *seriously* consider doing what trojanfoe suggests in his answer. Have the program check for the proper arguments, and if present, just run. if not, then prompt the user for them in your program. That answer deserves an up-vote, which I'm going to give it, as should you. Between that answer and this one, you will be very well covered for input-processing.

Comment: That is absolutely true, but for this assignment it just needed to be input from the terminal

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you want to get your arguments from the command line and if they are missing, prompt the user for them

Lets assume you want the arguments: number word number

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int number1;
char word[128];
int number2;

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    if (argc == 4)
    {
        number1 = atoi(argv[1]);
        strcpy(word, argv[2]);
        number2 = atoi(argv[3]);
    }
    else
    {
        do
            printf("Enter number word number: ");
        while (scanf("%d %s %d", &number1, word, &number2) != 3);
    }

    printf("I got %d '%s' %d\n", number1, word, number2);
    return 0;
}
```

Which gives:

```
$ ./test
Enter number word number: 1 andy 12
I got 1 'andy' 12
$ ./test 2 pandy 56
I got 2 'pandy' 56
```

Note that the error-checking is poor in this example and can be improved alot (not using `atoi()` is one way to start).

Comment: +1 this is always a good idea when running a program that takes cmdline params as optional prompt-data, and is well-worthy of an up-vote.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to check argc in the program as RageD points out, otherwise when launching the program with insufficient arguments will cause problems.

gcc is the c compiler - it produces an executable. When you hit 'Run' in Xcode it compiles your program and then runs the executable file created. The executable created is named the same as your Xcode project name.

To run the program you built in Xcode from the command line:

- In Xcode's project navigator find the executable in the 'Products' folder
- Drag the executable file into Terminal (You will get an absolute url to the executable)
- add any arguments you need to run your program
- Hit enter!

The result will look something similar to the snippet below (for my 'MyCommandLineApp' project):

```
$ /Users/pliskin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyCommandLineApp-hbpuxhguakaagvdlpdmqczucadim/Build/Products/Debug/MyCommandLineApp argument1 argument2
```