# Set arguments in Xcode 6 OpenCV

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, hdrimages

I need to load some images and a `.txt` file from folder in order to create an HDR image with OpenCV 3.0.0 like [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/photo/hdr_imaging/hdr_imaging.html). Xcode seems to be linked with OpenCV 3.0.0 as other code samples work, images are loaded when I give the full path. How can I load images and `.txt` files directly from argument like I do in VS2010? I need to use the code as it is in the example.

```
    void loadExposureSeq(String path, vector<Mat>& images, vector<float>& times)
{
    path = path + std::string("/");
    ifstream list_file((path + "list.txt").c_str());
    string name;
    float val;
    while(list_file >> name >> val) {
        Mat img = imread(path + name);
        images.push_back(img);
        times.push_back(1 / val);
    }
    list_file.close();
}
```

I tried to enter the full path in `std::string("/")` but it didn't work.
I am very new to Xcode, please help!

Comment: Can this question be boiled down to "How do I specify command-line arguments when running a program from Xcode ? [If so, **read this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14815947/1322972).

Comment: Good to know. However, I still have the same error OpenCV Error: `Assertion failed (!images.empty()) in checkImageDimensions, file /Users/johnaros/Desktop/opencv/modules/photo/src/hdr_common.cpp, line 51
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/johnaros/Desktop/opencv/modules/photo/src/hdr_common.cpp:51: error: (-215) !images.empty() in function checkImageDimensions`

Comment: The test code needs to have the whole folder that contain all files as an argument. I put the full path of the whole folder under edit scheme setting. Is that correct?