# how to pass command-line arguments to a program run with the open command?

Tags: macos, bash

Is there a way to pass arguments to a program being run via:

```
open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app ~/my_executable
```

I have tried:

```
open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app ~/my_executable arg1 arg2
```

But this is interpreted as telling the terminal to open `~/my_executable ~/arg1 ~/arg2.`

I have tried:

```
open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app '~/my_executable arg1 arg2'
```

But it picks up arg1 and arg2 as if they were part of the path rather than arguments.

I have tried:

```
open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app ~/my_executable | xargs arg1 arg2
```

I have also tried:

```
open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app ~/my_executable --args arg1 arg2
```

But with that flag, args are passed to the terminal.

### NOTE

I am only allowed to change the arguments to Terminal.app (the part within [ ]):

```
open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app [~/my_executable arg1 arg2]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot just run the executable directly without using the `open` command?

Comment: Yeah because that is the command Xcode uses :/
[Trying to pass arguments to a program that uses ncurses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780301/how-to-run-command-line-application-from-the-terminal) (and must therefore be debugged in a terminal window).

Comment: What  you try putting --args in front of your ecexutable: `open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app --args ~/my_executable arg1 arg2` ?

Comment: That doesn't work either, @chown. You can try it yourself by opening a terminal and inputting this command.
`open -n -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app --args ~/my_executable arg1 arg2`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to create a temporary shell script, e.g.

```
$ echo "~/my_executable arg1 arg2" > /tmp/tmp.sh ; chmod +x /tmp/tmp.sh ; open -a Terminal /tmp/tmp.sh ; rm /tmp/tmp.sh
```

Comment: So making the terminal run a shell script which launches the executable with the arguments?
That'll work, as unfortunate as it is having to create and manage an extra shell script to do so.

Comment: Yes, I can't see a more elegant way unfortunately - it just seems to be a limitation that is not easy to work around.

Comment: Also, I had to add `sleep 2` command before `rm /tmp/tmp.sh` because rm command was running too soon.
So my final script was like this: `$ echo "~/my_executable arg1 arg2" > /tmp/tmp.sh ; chmod +x /tmp/tmp.sh ; open -a Terminal /tmp/tmp.sh ; sleep 2 ; rm /tmp/tmp.sh`

Answer (score 22):

**Edit:** Leaving the original answer below as some people seem to find it useful, but keep in mind that this doesn't really answers OP's question, this is to pass arguments to an app opened with "open" not to and app opened with Terminal.app which was opened with "open".

You can find your answer by running open without arguments:

`% open  Usage: open [-e] [-t] [-f] [-W] [-R] [-n] [-g] [-h] [-b <bundle identifier>] [-a <application>] [filenames] [--args arguments]`

[...]

`--args        All remaining arguments are passed in argv to the application's main() function instead of opened.`

[...]

You can see there is an option `--args` you can use it like this:

```
open ./Untitled.app --args arg1 arg2 arg3
```

I tested it on el Capitan (10.11.3) so I don't know if the option is present in earlier versions.

Comment: That works when you are opening an application directly, but OP is trying to get Terminal to run a command-line executable with parameters.

Comment: For some reason, --args is not working on my macOS Catalina 10.15.7 machine. The terminal app opens with the script file, but no arguments are passed to the script file.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't deserve all those upvotes as I didn't really understand the question. Try looking at the accepted answer. Unfortunately I don't think there is any other way to do this unless someone adds some more context on why this is needed (that is the question takes as an assumption that the open command is the only possible solution to the original unstated problem, which seems to be something to do with debugging cli tools in xcode... ).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I know. need to manage another script.
but think differently. you work not on Terminal, but on Script Editor.
(not bash scripting, but AppleScript'ing)

```
property testScript : "/tmp/sh.sh"

set input to display dialog "args?" default answer ""
log input
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script testScript & " " & text returned of input
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

For those with having an issue with Paul R's answer, add the `; rm /tmp/tmp.sh` to the tmp.sh script itself. Don't add a sleep command like Maksim as that creates a race condition.

```
echo "~/my_executable arg1 arg2 ; rm /tmp/tmp.sh" > /tmp/tmp.sh ; chmod +x /tmp/tmp.sh ; open -a Terminal /tmp/tmp.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `--args` switch before your arguments.

`open ./Terminal.app --args --your-args`

**From the docs:**

`--args: All remaining arguments are passed in argv to the application's main() function instead of opened.`

Comment: it doesn't answer the question how to run something in that Terminal window

Comment: @Gargo indeed it does not - but as I read it, that is not the question that was asked.