# How to pass an argument to the Java FX application when building install4j?

Tags: macos, associations, install4j

How to pass an argument to the Java FX application when building install4j? Works fine Windows.I prepare .exe and .dmg file on install4j. When i open application file on Windows args pass main method. But when i open this app on mac os args do not pass main function.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510815/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-program-run-with-the-open-command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pass command-line arguments to a program run with the open command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510815/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-program-run-with-the-open-command)