# Let Xcode’s “Run” start the executable in Terminal.app

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, ncurses

I am developing an ncurses program. So running this in Xcode fails because the Console is just for stdout/stderr, but it is not a full terminal emulation (and hence can’t run ncurses programs).

To easily use the debugger, I would like to tweak the Scheme that the “Run” feature starts the application in Terminal.app or iTerm.app instead.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? My first attempts to change the Executable in the “Run” section of the scheme editor to use Terminal.app and use arguments were not successful (but then again, I am not familiar with possible arguments for Terminal.app).

**Update**: Thanks for pointing to [How to run command-line application from the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780301/how-to-run-command-line-application-from-the-terminal) - this is indeed almost what I am after. The problem is that at least on OS X 10.11, SIP (System Integrity Protection) requires to turn off the "Debug Executable" option (besides, I don't want to debug Terminal.app, but rather my application).

So the remaining question is if it is possible to let the "Run" also start the debugger the debug the built executable (i.e. without manually attaching the debugger after the executable was started).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run command-line application from the terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780301/how-to-run-command-line-application-from-the-terminal)